# Can any one help me or suggest me about connect to web api in angular2 with type script

Tags: angular

Actually im struck with connect to web api and fetch data, in all examples they are explaining with local data and im confusing with these import statements, please can any one explain clearly.. thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out the help menu about what questions to ask and not to ask and how to ask good questions. Your question doesn't contain any useful information that would allow to diagnose your problem. There are lots of tutorials out there to teach you the first steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the HTTP module.  The http request will not fire until you Subscribe() to it (which will make it 'hot' / active)

Here's a basic example:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class TestComponent {
private data;
private error;

constructor(private http: Http) {
    callWebApi();
}

callWebApi()
{
    let url ='http://www.test.com/api/xyz';
    let body = {
        'Param1': 1234,
        'Param2': 5678
    };
    this.http.post(url, body)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            let rJson = data.json();
             // process json here
             alert('success');
        },
        error => {
          // handle error
             alert('error');
        });
}
}
```

Comment: is this service.ts file ?

Comment: Yes, in the example above, this would be a service, but you could use it in a component if you liked with some small changes.  To use the service, you would need to bootstrap it first, then import it in your component, and add it to the constructor.  e.g. constructor (private testService: TestService).  You could then call this.testService.callWebApi();

Comment: ok thanku, can u send me main.ts, app.component.ts, files for get request from fetching data from web api

Comment: sorry for askinng like this, bcz im very new to this angular2, but any how i want learn, tomrow i have to show my tl thats why

Comment: Just add @Component above the export class to turn it into a component

Comment: I've updated the code so it's now using a component called test

Comment: Some links that might help - 1. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/  2. https://www.ng-book.com/2/  3. https://egghead.io/courses/angular-2-fundamentals